# In Cassandra, how do I access historical data?

Tags: database, cassandra

Cassandra uses a timestamp system to serve up the most recent records. How do I display a list of all values & timestamps for a particular column?

For example, I run this command for a Column family called 'Users':

`set Users[jsmith][first]='John'`

When I get the 'first' column, I see the following:

`get Users[jsmith][first]
=> (column=first value=John, timestamp=1287604215498000`

Then, I update the 'first' column to Charlie.
`set Users[jsmith][first]='Charlie'`

I will now see the following

`get Users[jsmith][first]
=> (column=first value=Charlie, timestamp=1299980101189000`

My question is how do I get all values (over time) for this column? I want to see something like `get Users[jsmith][first] ==> John (timestamp), Charlie (timestamp)`.

Comment: I see that blogger [Jerome Verstrynge had the same questions](http://adamman71.blogspot.com/2010/11/timestamps-in-cassandra.html) and came to the conclusion that timestamps won't provide historical data on their own. I'd need to create my own column to collect the time data.

Comment: Hi, link has been moved to: [here](http://jverstry.blogspot.com/2010/11/timestamps-in-cassandra.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. Cassandra departs from the BigTable model here: only the most recent version is retained.